# Distribution of the negative sign to the components of the vectors in a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Is there any vector space $V$ such that $\exists A \in V$ where $A=(a_1,a_2, ...,a_n)$ and $-A \ne (-a_1,-a_2, ...,-a_n)$?

In case failed my translation from English to math:

I am basically just trying to see if there exist a counter example for the proposition that you can just distribute the negative sign to the components of any vector in any vector spaces regardless of the field, the definition of addition and the definition of scalar multiplication for that vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For any $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ where $a=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$, by *definition*, $-a=(b_1,\cdots,b_n)$ is a vector such that $a+(-a)=0$. It follows by the definition of vector addition that $b_k=-a_k$ for each $k$.

In general, for an abstract vector space $V$, you can only write $v$ as an n-tuple when you have an ordered basis of $V$.

Comment: So there is no way of changing the definition of vector addition and the definition of scalar multiplication in a way that would make this no longer valid without having those definitions contradict the vector space axioms?

Comment: @Neurolife77: No. This is a consequence of the vector space axioms.